# Pandas read_table() -- How to Work with multiple custom NA formats?

Tags: python, pandas

I have data in the form:

```
000000008,2, 1,000000009,H,9740,000000008
000000009,1, 1,000000009,G,8790,000000008
000000010,1, 1,000000009,A,4081,000000008
000000011,2, 1,        ., ,   .,000000011
000000012,3, 1,        ., ,   .,        .
000000013,2, 1,        ., ,   .,000000013
```

You can see some values are missing in the last 3 rows and this is the problem: how do I convert to the right data type and handle these cases for a large dataset?

For certain columns, if the value is missing, I want to exclude those rows, for others I'd like to set it to some value.

Here is my code:

```
inputDBFilename = inputDir + 'testData.txt'

df = pd.read_table(inputDBFilename, delimiter=',',
                   names=('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'),
                   na_values=['        .'],
                   dtype={'A': np.uint64, 'B': np.uint8, 'C': np.uint8, 'D': np.uint64,
                          'E': np.str, 'F': np.uint16, 'G': np.uint64})
```

I am getting the error:

```
ValueError: Integer column has NA values in column 3
```

But why is this an error -- it should expect those NA values!!

Comment: You can't have `NaN` values in an `int` column, `NaN` is a float.

Comment: The problem is that numpy has no `NaN`/null object for `int`-types. This is a well documented issue, and one of the reasons pandas will eventually move away from numpy, and move instead to Apache Arrow.

Comment: Thanks! I converted to float and it works!

Answer (score 0):

You can directly specify your consumer NA value format when reading the CSV. If there are more than one type of NA value string, supply a list to the `na_values` argument

```
In [62]:
T = '''000000008,2, 1,000000009,H,9740,000000008
000000009,1, 1,000000009,G,8790,000000008
000000010,1, 1,000000009,A,4081,000000008
000000011,2, 1,        ., ,   .,000000011
000000012,3, 1,        ., ,   .,        .
000000013,2, 1,        ., ,   .,000000013'''

from io import StringIO
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(T), na_values=['        .', '   .'], header=None)
df

Out[62]:
    0  1  2    3  4       5     6
0   8  2  1  9.0  H  9740.0   8.0
1   9  1  1  9.0  G  8790.0   8.0
2  10  1  1  9.0  A  4081.0   8.0
3  11  2  1  NaN        NaN  11.0
4  12  3  1  NaN        NaN   NaN
5  13  2  1  NaN        NaN  13.0
```